# Saving enum with custom id in grails mongodb

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I was under the wrong impression of saving enum type as ordinal values after completion of the issue https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-232 that we can now save enum with the custom id.

For example:

This won't save field **type** with values either 2 or 3.

```
package test

class User {

    static mapping = {
        //type enumType: "ordinal"
    }

    UserType type

    String name
}

enum UserType {
    A(2),
    B(3),

    int getId() {
        this.id
    }

    final int id
    UserType(int id) {
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

How can we save enum with custom ids (as shown above) in a grails app with mongodb plugin installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone need this feature. Now mongodb also supports saving enum with custom id as explained in the question.

The changes required are already merged by pull request https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/pull/41 and they just have to release a new version of mongodb or GORM.

Comment: if I have an ordinal emum, but in mongo I want it to store as a string as in the older version of the plugin, it looks like I now have to create a 'customTypeMarshaller' but I am not seeing any documentation on how/where to do that.

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything if you have not defined `id` in domain your enum class and no mapping for that enum field.

Comment: I do want the id on the enum, but in mongo I want it to store the toString version not the id. how can I pull that off?

Comment: specifically there is a method to check for 'customTypeMarshaller' before it checks if it is an Enum in MappingFactory.java but I haven't been able to figure out how to include one of those.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked Grails 2.4 yet, but in 2.3.8 (or at least in grails-datastore-core 3.1.0) you can't.

The issue that you referenced referred to the using [built-in ordinal value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) of the Enum class, not a property value. What you want is a [custom type marshaller](https://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/engine/types/CustomTypeMarshaller.html) (or perhaps the subclass [AbstractMappingAwareCustomTypeMarshaller](https://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/engine/types/AbstractMappingAwareCustomTypeMarshaller.html)). Unfortunately, Grails checks to see if a property is an enum before considering a custom type mapper. From org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.GormMappingConfigurationStrategy#getPersistentProperties():

```
else if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(currentPropType) ||
       propertyFactory.isSimpleType(propertyType)) {
    persistentProperties.add(propertyFactory.createSimple(entity, context, descriptor));
}
else if (MappingFactory.isCustomType(propertyType)) {
    persistentProperties.add(propertyFactory.createCustom(entity, context, descriptor));
}
```

I'd say that this is a bug and if it is still present in 2.4.4 (or whatever the latest version currently is) then it should be reported to Grails.

Comment: Thank you @jgibson for taking time on this. Actually I forgot to answer my own question. I investigated the GORM code like you did and submitted a pull request for the same feature and they have already merged it. Please have a look at here https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/pull/41

Comment: Thanks for fixing this! I've been too busy to make the jump to 2.4, but it's good to know that when I get there I'll get to have custom enum mapping.